# What would be the best way to listen to changes in a database?

Tags: node.js, database

I want to build a small program where, through a json file, I configure which tables of a database listen and show on the screen the changes that are made in real time. I plan to do it with NodeJs, although I do not know if it is the best option, and if I choose NodeJS, I do not know very well where to start.
Could someone give me a starting point or some idea of where to start reading?

Comment: You can’t _listen_ to a database. You can make requests to it periodically to see if something has changed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the events of DB inserts to solve this issue.

If you are using an ORM like [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) or any other ORM, they should have [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html) or its equivalent. Essentially they are the life cycle events which are triggered when any event on that model would happen.

Now all you need is on every such event, we write to a new table which list the table which has been modified and at what time. Now the front end can make periodic request to this table and find out the diff by either sending the last timestamp or the ID.

Disadvantage of this method is that every write is essentially two writes into the database. The advantage is your read query to find the diff would only make one request to one table which is better. You can store more information in this new table depending on the information you need on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look of it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events. This is npm package to listen database changs.